# Make custom location annotations in using Mapbox

Tags: swift, geocoding, mapbox, reverse-geocoding

I am using Mapbox to create my app. When I click a button I would like it to mark my current location and add a marker to it as it currently does. I then would like the abiilty to tap on this marker and have it display the current location information such as the adress of the marked point.

Right now all I have is...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTnhg.jpg

I would like to note that I am using Xcode 9.1 and Swift 4. Thank you for all your feedback in advance.

Currently the swift file looks like...

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Mapbox
import MapKit
import MapboxGeocoder

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MGLMapViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

let geocoder = Geocoder.shared

let dismissesAutomatically: Bool = false
let isAnchoredToAnnotation: Bool = true

weak var delegate: MGLCalloutViewDelegate?

let tipHeight: CGFloat = 10.0
let tipWidth: CGFloat = 20.0

@IBOutlet var mapView: MGLMapView!
let manager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
manager.delegate = self
manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

@IBAction func markStuff(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBAction func refLocation(_ sender: Any) {
manager.startUpdatingLocation()

}
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
return true
}


func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
return nil
}

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, tapOnCalloutFor annotation: MGLAnnotation)
{

 print("tap on callout")

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
let location = locations[0]

let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)

mapView.setCenter(center, zoomLevel: 10, animated: true)

let annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()

annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate

mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)

annotation.title = "Testing"
annotation.subtitle = "\(annotation.coordinate.latitude), \(annotation.coordinate.longitude)"

self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a subclass of [MGLUserLocationAnnotationView](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.0/Classes/MGLUserLocationAnnotationView.html), then use that as your view for the `MGLUserLocation` annotation.

For example, if your custom subclass was called `YourLocationAnnotationView()`, you could do something like:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {This custom view is created below.
     if annotation is MGLUserLocation && mapView.userLocation != nil {
        return YourLocationAnnotationView()
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

For a complete implementation, [see this example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/user-location-annotation/) from the official documentation.

Comment: How is this usable in combination with MGLMapCamera?